# IPv6 link-local addresses for virtual interfaces are identical - how to assign "link-unique"?

Tags: ipv6, ip-link-local

I have a VPN connecting two virtual interfaces of two hosts. Both VPN interfaces have MAC addresses 00:00:00:00:00:00, as the OS (Linux) assigns link-local IPv6 address based on MAC address. So the link-local IPv6 addresses are identical for both peers. This breaks OSPFv3 (at least).

What is the right way to obtain IPv6 addresses, which would be unique on the link, for such interfaces? I expect that I'd not need to configure a new IPv6 network and manually assign addresses from it to VPN endpoints.

Comment: Hi there, this quesction is off topic as it relates to specific server coniguration so it would be better suited on another StackExchange website like "ServerFault" or "Unix & Linux". Just as a side note though, surely the obvious answer here is to assign a MAC address to each virtual NIC. Look up a free MAC address in the IANA registry.

Comment: Why not configure your interfaces to use something other than an invalid MAC address? Many network devices will drop traffic that contains an all zero MAC address as invalid. This would also solve your IPv6 problem.

Comment: @jwbensley It seems to me that the material question here is "What is the right way to obtain IPv6 addresses, which would be unique on the link, for such interfaces?" which seems to be squarely on topic for networking.SE.

Comment: @alx9r It is within the RFC for there to be two interfaces on one device and have them both use the same link-local address.  The OS will typically assign an interface identifier to distinguish one link-local "network" from the next.  For example, my Win7 box's SLAAC generated IPv6 address is:  `fe80::8dcf:9f11:dec9:527c%23`, and the `%23` is what identifies that particular interface.   Now, if some external application has issues with that, then the solution is to manually assign link-local addresses as necessary.

Comment: @alx9r - Yes I agree with what you are saying, however having two interface with all zero's MAC address, it could cause an issue for the underlying protocols so best practice would probably be to fix that. By way of fixing that the OP wouldn't have this problem (most likely). As Eddie has said, there is a work around for having two link-local addresses on the same box within the RFC, but that's assuming the interface has a MAC address which the OP's does not...

Comment: The OP is getting two duplicate addresses because the virtual interfaces have duplicate/missing MACs, solving this at the IP layer isn't fixing the underlying issue but working around it. That is my point, fix the underlying MAC issue.

Comment: @jwbensley: MAC addresses for physical devices are guaranteed to be unique by their vendors. You suggest that they should be unique *also* for VPN endpoints. My question is, how to get uniqueness in this case.

Comment: @user3608247 They aren't gurenteed to be unique by vendors for physical devices, I have seen dup MACs multiple times on seperate devices. Moving on, assign MACs from an unassigned range by IANA is one method. How do you think virtual machines work? People assign blocks of MAC address from IANA and then hypervisors can assign those MACs to VM as they are spun up in a DHCP type fasion but for layer 2.

Comment: perhaps what you want is Unique Local Addresses see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address to get a unique prefix you can use https://www.sixxs.net/tools/grh/ula/